# IE9 encoding problem

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, encoding

In one of my asp.net-applications I found a strange behaviour produced in Internet Explorer 9 while IE8 works well.

As the default encoding I need utf-8. That's important because I use german so called Umlaute like "ÄäÖüÜü".

When the page is loaded for the first time IE9 decides to use "Western Europe" Encoding. That's ISO 8859-1 as far as I know and the Umlaute change to strange letters.
On the second load IE9 uses utf-8 correctly.
In the sourcecode I tried the following things to tell IE which encoding to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 TRANSITIONAL//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Why does IE9 work so strange on the first load?
And what else can I try to tell IE9 how to work

Comment: the server return the right enconding in all other pages and the error can reproduced on 2 servers.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> contains your mentioned <meta charset=utf-8> isn't it the same?

Comment: I see, 1 and 2 points ok! Let's check third reason. Open your master page in WinHex or something similar, and post first 10 bytes in hexademical format or screnshot of it.

Comment: ∩╗┐<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="dispForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="dispForm" %>♪◙<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W

Comment: EF BB BF 3C 25 40 20 50 61 67 65 20 4C 61 6E 67 
75 61 67 65 3D 22 43 23 22 20 41 75 74 6F 45 76 
65 6E 74 57 69 72 65 75 70 3D 22 74 72 75 65 22 
20 43 6F 64 65 46 69 6C 65 3D 22 64 69 73 70 46 
6F 72 6D 2E 61 73 70 78 2E 63 73 22 20 49 6E 68 
65 72 69 74 73 3D 22 64 69 73 70 46 6F 72 6D 22    
20 25 3E 0D 0A 3C 21 44 4F 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 
74 6D 6C 20 50 55 42 4C 49 43 20 22 2D 2F 2F 57 
33 43 2F 2F 44 54 44 20 58 48 54 4D 4C 20 31 2E
these are the entries i get, when opening aspx-file in hex-editor

Comment: It's normal too, save you page to UTF-8 without BOM it will remove first three bytes (maybe it help). I don't know any other reason for this bug. Last suggestion is try to save your page as html, and periodicly remove some parts of html-code with looking when it fail's get off.

Comment: I've got additional information. The page making the problem is opened in a popup window by javascript(window.open). when opening the page by directly typing it's url it is always shown correctly. that's what i found out today. probably it's a javascript problem, but i still don't know how to handle it.
thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstable - server where you host your site can return wrong encoding information in header;

Two - maybe it's some fail in string that tolk about encoding in the header of your page (wrong symbol in that string).

Three - open you page in Hex brouser (WinHex for example) and post first row of code (sometimes editor place wrong data in first byte, I've stumble on it once)

If this site is placed online, post it's url and I try to find a problem.

Comment: The page is intranet only. I posted the http response and it seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Check response header of you server it must contains something like this:

Key Value

Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8

Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

if it's not then check you server settings or you code there must be place where Content-type header changes

EDIT: ok, encoding is right, as suggested in the comment you shoul check first bytes of you response, it seems like it starts with additional bytes (usually info about encoding)

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 123702
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET